# Import ansicolor python functions and use them only terminal

Tags: python

Is there a better way to write this piece of code below?

```
yellow = green = red = lambda msg: msg
if sys.stdout.isatty():
  try:
    from colors import yellow, green, red
  except ImportError:
    pass
```

The rest of the code will use yellow("something"), green("something") and will not have to worry about if it terminal or log file.

Comment: Spent a few minutes trying to figure out a better way -- didn't think of anything.  For whatever that's worth.

Comment: My only criticism would be with regards to portability, i.e. requiring a third-party module, when you can probably achieve the same thing with the built-in [`curses`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) module. The built-in module would probably handle different terminal types better also.

Comment: @Aya: `ansicolor` works on Windows, and non-`curses`-compatible terminals on POSIX, and can even generate "ANSI art" text files. So, in some ways it's a lot _more_ portable. But a more accurate thing to say would be that they're pretty different modules, appropriate for pretty different use cases.

Comment: I am not worried about portability. That's functional aspects. My question is on readability + style.

Comment: @SenthilKumaran In that case, I'd leave is as-is.

Comment: @abarnert Good point. Although if portability were a concern, I'd still `try` to `import curses` and use `tigetstr()` or somesuch to get the appropriate control code before falling back to some other method. Given how trivial the `ansicolor` source code actually is, I'd probably inline it to remove the dependency.

Comment: @abarnert - Appreciate it for the last comment. This kind of discussion is harmful when a complete newbie looks at this question in the future and finds the above irrelevant discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was some discussion on the best way to write this on the mailing lists a while back (as part of the ongoing Python 3 process of turning every C-only module into a Python module with a C accelerator).

The parallel isn't perfect, because these are functions being exported by a module to be used as part of the stdlib, rather than functions to be used in the current script. But I think it's close enough to use as a guide—just like you, they're defining fallback methods, then trying to import implementations over them.

The consensus—or at least what's implemented as of 3.3—seems to be pretty much exactly what you're doing, with some minor wrinkles.

---

When the imported module is being written specifically to be used by the importing code, just use a `from foo import *`, as in [`elementtree`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#l1705), you just use `from _elementtree import *`.

---

When it's conceivable that you might need to access the fallback functions even when the real ones are available, as in [`pickle`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/pickle.py#l1348), do this:

```
_yellow = _green = _red = lambda msg: msg
if sys.stdout.isatty():
    try:
        from colors import yellow, green, red
    except ImportError:
        yellow, green, red = _yellow, _green, _red
else:
    yellow, green, red = _yellow, _green, _red
```

Although in this case, I'd probably write it as:

```
_yellow = _green = _red = lambda msg: msg
yellow, green, red = _yellow, _green, _red
if sys.stdout.isatty():
    try:
        from colors import yellow, green, red
    except ImportError:
        pass
```

---

If neither of those wrinkles applies, just do exactly what you're doing.

Comment: It would still need to define the symbols if `sys.stdout.isatty()` returns `False`.

Comment: I've done a quick grep through the stdlib looking for possible exceptions. For example, [`threading`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/threading.py#l918) moved the pure-Python implementation into a separate module, so it does a try…import…except…import. Anyway, the stdlib may not be quite as consistent as my answer makes it out to be, but I think the answer still stands.